# How can I update Docker image after changing few lines of code in my app?

Tags: docker, deployment, dockerfile

[Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPOLW.png) I just built a Docker image using the below command in my app working directory:

```
docker build -t imagename:latest .
```

The Docker image is successfully built after a few minutes and the application is running as well once I used the below command:

```
docker run -p portnumber:portnumber imagename:latest
```

But now I want to update 2 lines of code in my application codebase. Suppose I added the code and wants to see if my application is working or not so how could I do that? Do I need to follow the below steps?

```
1. Delete the Docker image
2. Rebuild the image using the above command
3. See if the app is working or not using the "docker run" command?
```

I want to know that how can I update my Docker image? My Dockerfile is the same and there won't be any changes. I don't want to rebuild the whole Docker image again because initially, the size of all packages were around 2GB. Can anyone help me that what should I do next? Thanks in advance.

OS: **Ubuntu**
Application framework: **Streamlit**

Comment: You can build the new image before stopping the old container, if that helps your workflow, but fundamentally, yes.

Comment: i am also trouble this using nodejs,.. all i want to do is just update the image,.. not removing image and build again because some node packages is long time to install,..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you asked specifically how to update (rebuild) your docker image, it is my guess that you are in fact in need of a different solution.

If you are developing on a dockerized version of your application (which is good), it is impractical to rebuild the image with every change you do in your code.

A better, and more common approach, is to mount your local folder into the container, so the running container and your local machine actually share a folder.

This way you can just edit your code, and it is reflected in the container immediately.

So, your `docker run` command might look something like this:

```
$ docker run -v $PWD:/path/to/app/in/container -p PORT:PORT IMAGE_NAME
```

- Read more about [docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).
- Read more about [docker for development environments](https://docs.docker.com/language/nodejs/develop/).
- Read about [using docker-compose for development](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-development-with-docker-compose).

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilding your docker image might not be as much as a hassle as you think !

When you build an image, each line with the command RUN, COPY or ADD of your Dockerfile is made into a layer of your image. When you rebuild the image, only the updated lines of the Dockerfile should rebuild. If you do not delete the old image so that it's in cache, that is.

If you try it, you should see only one or so layers of your image updating (and those below it)

An alternative would be to not put your code into your build and to insert it in the container with a volume at runtime. Depending on your use, it could be something. But it is a quite different use case and might not apply.

Comment: Let me try the first approach. Seems logical and I missed that. The same way we do "git commit"..... Thanks very much.

Comment: HI Faeeria, No. It definitely updated the image but still installing all the libraries and packages from the start. I don't want to install it all over again as I am short with Internet speed here.

Comment: Do you install the libraries before or after adding the code ? Could you post your Dockerfile?

Comment: Yes, I just updated the question where I have inserted the screenshot of my Dockerfile. I created the Dockerfile, built the image and then I remembered to add few more lines. When I again rebuilt the image with the same command, It reinstalled all the packages again. I don't want this.

Comment: Do you delete the image before rebuilding it ?

Comment: No, I didn't delete the image.